# 240v to 120v by using only one leg?

Tags: electrical

I have an unused 240v 50 amp circuit. I would like to put a 15 amp 120v hardwired load on one of the legs. Is this ok? Is there an issue of current imbalance?

Comment: USA/Canada, presumably?

Comment: Yep, USA. I'll add that the circuit does have a 240v 50 amp outlet on it as well.

Comment: Can you open up the outlet box for that outlet and post a photo of its innards?

Answer (score 4):

You would first need to change the breaker from 50A to 15A.

Your 50A circuit needs to be one with a neutral (in terms of a typical range outlet, a 4-prong, not a 3-prong.)

At that point, not a problem (assuming you are on normal USA/Canada 120/240 split-phase, 120V to neutral power.)

**However**, you might find more use in putting a sub-panel fed by the 50A breaker, which could then have the 15A breaker you need to protect your load (which you cannot just hook up to a 50A breaker directly.) You could power multiple other things from the sub-panel, if you have other things to power.

"Current imbalance" is not a concern - you have that any time you have a single 120V load running, and it's mostly a consideration when you have two such loads that you expect to be on at the same time, in which case, it's good to put them on opposite hots.

Comment: What if the load has it's own breaker?

Comment: That does not protect the **input wiring** to the load and its breaker. Truly, you don't want 50A available where 15A will do - you can make an impressive fireball without tripping a 50A breaker - my oven element did that once.

Comment: @ViktorPokrachinskiy -- whatever breaker is in the load is probably not *as good at breaking faults* as the breaker you find in a proper electrical panel